# make geth fails after cloning ethereum classic repo

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-classic

After cloning ethereum classic repo, running "make geth" command leads to the following error:

cannot load hash/maphash: malformed module path "hash/maphash": missing dot in first path element

I also tried with the last commit of their release version but I get the same issue!

Does it mean they don't test their releases? How to fix it?

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: Are you running Linux or another OS ?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 20

Comment: @hroussille thanks for help if you have an idea please let me know. I'm on a digital ocean ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @hroussille going back to this release solved this issue. https://github.com/etclabscore/core-geth/releases/tag/v1.12.0

Comment: Latest release (v1.10.15 commit 8be800ffa9c4992666e2620e0ab4725a1a83352b) builds fine for me (I can only test on windows right now :/).  The master branch is not stable, maybe that's what you used ? They do test their release, don't worry. Try again after running `git checkout v1.10.15`

Comment: @hroussille ok thanks for info! Yes I used branch master. I think you meant v1.12.5 not v1.10.15 right?

Comment: No, i meant v1.10.15 (Faryar) that's currently the latest stable release :
 https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases

Comment: Ah ok, it seems we are not talking about the same repo. I'm talking about ethereum classic (https://github.com/etclabscore/core-geth/releases)